# Angular directive: compile is invoked, but not link

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).directive('myDir', function () {
  return {
    scope: {},
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function () {
      alert('hello!');
    }
  };
});
```

And I'm using it in a template like so:

```
<my-dir attr1="hello" attr2="world" />
```

When I load the page, I don't get the alert. However, if all I do is assign the `compile` property instead of the `link` property, I get the alert. Why is it not invoking my `link` function, but it's happily invoking `compile`?

Note: I even tried to return a `pre`/`post` link object from the `compile` function, yet it still doesn't invoke anything. It also doesn't matter if I make the `<my-dir>` self-closing (as above) or not.

Comment: I tried the same code but its working with the same code, I am not sure why it is not working for you

Answer (score 1):

Same code is working for me check this

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]).directive('myDir', function () {
        return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function () {
          alert('hello!');
        }
      };
   });
  </script>
 <body ng-app="myApp">
    <my-dir attr1="hello" attr2="world" />
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this.

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

        app.directive('myDir', myfunc);

        function myfunc() {
            return {
                scope: {},
                restrict: 'E',
                link: function () {
                    alert('hello!');
                }
            };
        };
```